# Drag & Drop com parametro

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Estou fazendo um formulário dinâmico. Onde tem um botão que adiciona o tipo do campo (Data, Hora,Texto, Email,etc). E queria fazer a ordenação desses campos com drag and drop.
Precisaria que retornasse a posição dos campos, pois vou salvar a ordem, o tipo e os valores em um banco.

O usuário vai poder criar vários tipos de formulários, com os campos que quiser, e depois, na hora de listar, teria que ter exibir os campos na ordem que ele deixou com o drag and drop.

Atualmente meu código ja esta criando os campos, e salvando no banco. Mas sem a possibilidade do usuário ordenar.
Ai teria que adicionar mais uma coluna no BD para saber a posição que o plugin retornar.

Alguém conhece algum plugin que faça algo parecido com isso ?

Os plugins que achei até agora, de form build nao mostrava a posição dos campos.

Answer (score -1):

Próprio JQuery pode ordenar os elementos com o Draggable. Veja um exemplo da funcionalidade:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Depois você pega uma lista com os elementos e manda pro backend. Ele já ficará ordenado no html com o Draggable, logo, você pode mandar a posição de acordo com o css/xpath do campo, pegando qual o número do elemento que ele está

Comment: Obrigado ao anônimo pelo downvote silencioso depois de 7 anos de resposta. Se a resposta não te ajudou, procure atualizá-la com uma abordagem mais recente para o problema + tecnologias que o rapaz citou.